# A question on finding the probability of getting spades in a slot machine.

Tags: probability

Assume that the slot machine has 1-slot. So this will be the outcomes;

$\begin{array} {|r|r|}\hline \spadesuit \\ \hline \heartsuit \\ \hline \diamondsuit \\ \hline \clubsuit \\ \hline  \end{array}$

Therefore the probability of getting a spade will be $\frac{1}{4}$. Now expand that to two slots and we'll get this;

$\begin{array} {|r|r|}\hline \spadesuit & \spadesuit \\ \hline \spadesuit & \heartsuit \\ \hline \spadesuit & \diamondsuit \\ \hline \spadesuit & \clubsuit \\ \hline  \end{array}$$,$$\begin{array} {|r|r|}\hline \heartsuit & \spadesuit \\ \hline \heartsuit & \heartsuit \\ \hline \heartsuit & \diamondsuit \\ \hline \heartsuit & \clubsuit \\ \hline  \end{array}$$,$$\begin{array} {|r|r|}\hline \diamondsuit & \spadesuit \\ \hline \diamondsuit & \heartsuit \\ \hline \diamondsuit & \diamondsuit \\ \hline \diamondsuit & \clubsuit \\ \hline  \end{array}$$,$$\begin{array} {|r|r|}\hline \clubsuit & \spadesuit \\ \hline \clubsuit & \heartsuit \\ \hline \clubsuit & \diamondsuit \\ \hline \clubsuit & \clubsuit \\ \hline  \end{array}$

I did this out horizontally so as to save space, the commas denote that. Btw, the order in which does matter (so ($\clubsuit$,$\diamondsuit$) and ($\diamondsuit$,$\clubsuit$) are treated differently). Now for two slots, we get the probability of spotting spades in this outcome to be $\frac{7}{16}$.

My question is for $n$, no. of slots and $m$, no. of suits (here we have $m=4$, because there are four suits). What will be the probability of spotting one suit?

Comment: Well, the probability of missing the given suit on a single slot is $\frac {m-1}m$.  So the probability of missing it on all the slots is $\left( \frac {m-1}m\right)^n$.  All you need to do is subtract that from $1$ since "seeing the given suit at least once" is the compliment of "never seeing the given suit".

Comment: @lulu, that's the answer! why didn't you answer this btw? thanks a bunch neverthless

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments:

It is easier to work from the complementary event, namely "the suit is never seen".

Since the probability that we miss the given suit on a given slot is $\frac {m-1}m$ we see that the answer is $$1-\left( \frac {m-1}m\right)^n$$

Sanity check:  For $m=4$, $n=2$ we have $$1-\left(\frac 34\right)^2=1-\frac 9{16}=\frac 7{16}$$ which is consistent with the prior example.